# NSDate date not returning current date and time after waking

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've noticed that [NSDate date] returns old date and times soon after waking from sleep.  I can't find any information around the specification of this, or how to refresh the current date and time after waking.

Does anyone have any information on the behavior?

Comment: That sounds like a fairly serious bug - are you certain you aren't looking at some cached copy of the `NSDate` object?

Comment: Right after waking I call [NSDate date] in the viewWillLoad method.  My understanding was since this is a class method, it isn't cached and should always return the current date and time.  But if I call [NSDate date] a little later, then it does return the current date and time.  So I suspect a timing issue in iOS around when this is updated after waking.

Comment: @trojanfoe: your question caused me to look at this in a new light.  The issue I'm having is not this at all.  It is some old NSURLConnection objects that had not completed before sleeping starting up again after waking with the old timestamp.  I had thought I had completed all old transactions before sleeping, but that is not the case.  So I mistakenly concluded the issues was with NSDate.

Comment: The real problem is not yet solved, but very solvable.  This particular question though is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving `NSDate` in an ivar and checking it after the app is relaunched? It'll be the old date if this is the case.

You could re-initialize the ivar on `viewWillAppear`, or do it in your `AppDelegate`. Alternatively you can also set it to `nil` on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try handling the [`applicationSignificantTimeChange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationSignificantTimeChange%3a) app delegate method or the [`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification) notification.

From the `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` documentation:

> If your application is currently suspended, this message is queued
>   until your application returns to the foreground, at which point it is
>   delivered. If multiple time changes occur, only the most recent one is
>   delivered.

It may be that you have to wait until this point before you can get accurate data from the NSDate class. Your views are probably being loaded too early.

It's probably better to do this kind of thing in `viewWillAppear:` however, and I have a feeling if you do this you can avoid dealing with the significant time change events.